# Oninput/Onchange not activating function

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an app that calculates the difference in days. There are several options for dates that may or may not be used. Because of this, I am building a switch/case logic flow to calculate different variable combinations. Everything works EXCEPT I cannot seems to get function add_sd() and add_td() to update their respective variables (using either onchange or oninput) and pass to the switch case. If I hard code "2" into date_list the expected output (difference in days) is produced in the Number of days box. As is, nothing appears in the Number of Days box. The relevant portions of the abbreviated code is below:

Code

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function calcBusinessDays(d1, d2) { 
            var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
            var d1_days = parseInt(d1.getTime()/one_day) - 1;
            var d2_days = parseInt(d2.getTime()/one_day);
            var days = (d2_days - d1_days);
            var weeks = (d2_days - d1_days) / 7;
            var day1 = d1.getDay();
            var day2 = d2.getDay();
            if (day1 == 0) {
                days--;
            } else if (day1 == 6) {
                days-=2;
            }
            if (day2 == 0) {
                days-=2;
            } else if (day2 == 6) {
                days--;
            }
            days -= parseInt(weeks) * 2;
            return days;
            }

        var add_sd_var=0;
        var add_td_var=0;
        function add_sd(){
            add_sd_var = 1;
            return add_sd_var;
            }

        function add_td(){
            var add_td_var = 1;
            return add_td_var;
            }

        var date_list; 

        function GetDays(){
                var days_left = 7;
                var num_day, num_day2 = 0;

                var start_date = new Date(document.getElementById("start_date").value);
                var today_date = new Date(document.getElementById("today_date").value);

                date_list = add_sd_var + add_td_var;

                switch(date_list){
                    case 2:
                    num_day = calcBusinessDays(start_date, today_date);
                    num_day2 = days_left - num_day;  
                    document.getElementById("numdays2").value = num_day2;  
                    break;
                }             
                }  
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    <Fieldset>
    <label class="form">Received by Client Date:</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="start_date" name="start_date" onchange="add_sd()"/> <br></br>

    <label class="form">Today's Date:</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="today_date" name="today_date" onchange="add_td()"/> <br></br>

    <label for="numdays2", class="form">Number of days:</label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="numdays2" name="numdays2"/> <br></br>

    <button id="enter" type="button" onclick="GetDays()">Enter</button>

    </Fieldset>
    </p>

</body>
```

Comment: think that you declare variable `add_sd` with value `0`, right after that you say that  `add_sd` is now a function and then inside the function you declare that `add_sd` is now 1... after first function call, `add_sd` trasnforms itself from a function to a number, it is not a function anymore. Change the variable or function name, they cannot be the same inside the same context

Comment: Take a look into https://momentjs.com/ powerful time manipulation/parsing library.

Comment: @calvin: That's a great observation and I changed it, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: *"it still doesn't work"*  is not very useful, can you provide us a [mcve] and explain what is not working, for example, did you get a console error? Did the current output is different from expected? Remember that you can [edit] your question to add those relevant informations

Comment: @David: This code is being embedded into a Google sites website. As far as I know, I can't import libraries.

Comment: Question and code updated to address Calvin's response.

Comment: Can you use normal modern JS instead? I.e. don't use legacy `on....` on HTML elements, but instead have a script that adds event listening to your DOM elements by querying for them and using `addEventListener`? Also in modern HTML5, no need for that `type` on the script: it's js by default, you only need it when you're _not_ using javascript. Similarly, unless you have a button inside a `<form>`, you don't need `type="button"`.

Comment: I'll try to use addEventListener. I looked at it earlier and wasn't seeing how to implement it. I am a part-time amateur front end coder. I build about 2-3 small HTML/JS apps a year for work. I don't exactly look at HTML/JS every day. Thanks for the tips on the tags.

Comment: You might want to try using `debugger;` in your code somewhere (probably at the beginning of your `add_sd()` and `add_td()` functions. If you have the development console open in your web browser then your code will stop at that point and you can step through to determine what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue seems to be that you are re-declaring `add_td_var` within your function, when it has already been declared outside the function. 
I amended this and also removed some invalid html breaks - `</br>`. In html 4 the break was `<br/>` (slash after), but in html5 it's just `<br>`, and it doesn't need a close tag. If you want another break, just add another `<br>`. In the below code (extra head/meta etc removed), the number of days appears in the box on button click.

Hope this helps

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcBusinessDays(d1, d2) {
    var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var d1_days = parseInt(d1.getTime() / one_day) - 1;
    var d2_days = parseInt(d2.getTime() / one_day);
    var days = (d2_days - d1_days);
    var weeks = (d2_days - d1_days) / 7;
    var day1 = d1.getDay();
    var day2 = d2.getDay();
    if (day1 == 0) {
      days--;
    } else if (day1 == 6) {
      days -= 2;
    }
    if (day2 == 0) {
      days -= 2;
    } else if (day2 == 6) {
      days--;
    }
    days -= parseInt(weeks) * 2;
    return days;
  }

  var add_sd_var = 0;
  var add_td_var = 0;

  function add_sd() {
    add_sd_var = 1;
    return add_sd_var;
  }

  function add_td() {
    add_td_var = 1;
    return add_td_var;
  }

  var date_list;

  function GetDays() {
    var days_left = 7;
    var num_day, num_day2 = 0;

    var start_date = new Date(document.getElementById("start_date").value);
    var today_date = new Date(document.getElementById("today_date").value);

    date_list = add_sd_var + add_td_var;

    switch (date_list) {
      case 2:
       //console.log("Date list: " + add_sd_var + " " +add_td_var);
        num_day = calcBusinessDays(start_date, today_date);
        num_day2 = days_left - num_day;
        document.getElementById("numdays2").value = num_day2;
        break;
    }
  }
</script>

<p>
  <Fieldset>
    <label class="form">Received by Client Date:</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="start_date" name="start_date" onchange="add_sd()" /> <br>

    <label class="form">Today's Date:</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="today_date" name="today_date" onchange="add_td()" /> <br>

    <label for="numdays2" , class="form">Number of days:</label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="numdays2" name="numdays2" /> <br>

    <button id="enter" type="button" onclick="GetDays()">Enter</button>

  </Fieldset>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it only worked when I removed the head and metadata that I, fortunately, do not need (besides re-declaring the add_td_var). Interestingly, the head and metadata was never a problem with other apps I created. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @Marty I only removed the head/metadata because it's surplus to requirements in the snippet, you shouldn't have problems with metadata. Maybe in future, recheck-your js, and try it with the js body before getting rid of your head data. Anyway, happy to help.. :)